# How to return index location in a listbox in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do you get the item's index location in a list box and return the position number instead of a string? I tried returning the index position, but my code only returns the string instead of the position number, here is my code

```
If lstRoomsOccupied.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
    strLocation = lstRoomsOccupied.Items(lstRoomsOccupied.SelectedIndex).ToString()
    strInput = InputBox("Enter the Number of Rooms Occupied on Floor " & strLocation.ToString())
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Select an item")
```

Can anyone help me how to return index position number?

Comment: SelectedIndex is 0 index so wouldn't doing "SelectedIndex + 1" give you the position number you are looking for?

Comment: How would I implement SelectedIndex + 1 to get the position number? I also tried removing .ToString but I'm not sure if ToString is the right way to return the position number?

Comment: A couple questions for you, what do you need this position for? How do you plan to use it after retrieving it?

Comment: Are you sure you just want the position (index) and not the value of the selected position? For instances position 1 could actually be value "4" depending on how you populate your listbox.

Answer (score 1):

Since, index is zero-based, then you need to `+1` the `SelectedIndex`, like this:

```
If lstRoomsOccupied.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
    strLocation = (lstRoomsOccupied.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString()
    strInput = InputBox("Enter the Number of Rooms Occupied on Floor " & strLocation)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Select an item")
End If
```

Note: You do not need to get the index of the item from the `.Items` collection, because all you care about is the index. You were getting the item's value, because you were asking for the selected item. Also, you do not need to `.ToString()` a string, because it is already a string.

Comment: Ok I tried this method, it seems to work, but my listbox shows values for example in order: "Floor 1 Occupied Room 21", "Floor 2 Occupied Room 15", "Floor 5 Occupied Room 2". When I select the second one, and click the button to begin my input, it shows this: "Enter the Number of Rooms Occupied on Floor: Floor 2 Occupied Room 15" when I want it to show: "Enter the Number of Rooms Occupied on Floor 2" which 2 is the second position in the list box

Comment: I am confused as to why the index of the selected item is the actual value you want to show, because like others have said the order of the list can be altered. It seems to me that you would want to show the value of the selected item instead of the index. Could you post the values in `lstRoomsOccupied`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your `Listbox` to a `ListView`, and setting the following:

```
  Me.ListView1.View = View.List
  Me.ListView1.MultiSelect = False
```

Then create the following `Class`:

```
  Public Class Rooms
     Public Floor As Integer
     Public Number As Integer
  End Class
```

Now, to add items to your `ListView` you can do the following:

```
    ' First create a 'Room' variable to store the Room's details
    Dim Room As New Rooms

    ' Set the floor number that the Room is on
    Room.Floor = 2

    ' Set the Room number
    Room.Number = 15

    ' Create a ListViewItem which will be added to the ListView
    Dim LVI As New ListViewItem
    LVI.Text = "Floor 2 Occupied Room 15"

    ' Now add the Room to the ListViewItem
    LVI.Tag = Room

    ' Add the ListViewItem to the ListView
    Me.ListView1.Items.Add(LVI)
```

When the user makes their selection, you can retrieve the information like so:

```
  Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get the Room's details
        Dim Room As Rooms = CType(Me.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Tag, Rooms)

        ' Add your code here
    End If

  End Sub
```

If you need the selected item's position in the list view, you can retrieve it with the following:

```
  If Me.ListView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Pos As Integer = Me.ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)
  End If
```

Comment: Ok I tried this method, it seems to work, but my listbox shows values for example in order: "Floor 1 Occupied Room 21", "Floor 2 Occupied Room 15", "Floor 5 Occupied Room 2". When I select the second one, and click the button to begin my input, it shows this: "Enter the Number of Rooms Occupied on Floor: Floor 2 Occupied Room 15" when I want it to show: "Enter the Number of Rooms Occupied on Floor 2" which 2 is the second position in the list box

Comment: @PatrickSerrano Okay, I think I understand what you are needing / wanting... I recommend changing the `Listbox` to a `ListView`, as the `ListView` uses `ListViewItem` which contains a property called `Tag`, which will allow you to store the required information in it. Using a `ListView` will also give you a LOT more flexabilty, although it will require a little more code, but trust me, it will be worth it. I'll edit my answer in the morning, showing you how to do this...

Comment: @PatrickSerrano I've edited / changed my answer to use a listview, which I feel would be better for your needs